# nginx logs move to backup location

Tags: linux, nginx, bash, logging

I have 3 nginx web servers which make big access.log log files.
I configured logrotate to rotate them when the size reaches 100mb and gzip them.

now i would like to move all the *.gz files at night to a backup CIFS location .
does anyone has a bash script which would handle it?

Comment: i guess i was too fast to open a question.

what i did was created a .crerentials file and put inside domain user and password

username=john.smith
password=123abc
domain=MYDOMAIN
chmod it to 500

make a bash script

#!/bin/sh    
smbclient //servername/share -A /root/.credentials -c "lcd /var/log/nginx; prompt; recurse; mput *.gz; "
rm /var/log/nginx/*.gz
and a crontab is runnging it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I was too fast to open a question. What I did was created a .credentials file and put inside domain user and password

```
username=john.smith 
password=123abc domain=MYDOMAIN
```

chmod it to 500 make a bash script

```
#!/bin/sh 
smbclient //servername/share -A /root/.credentials -c "lcd /var/log/nginx; prompt; recurse; mput .gz; " 
rm /var/log/nginx/.gz
```

and a crontab is running it